# Could maintenance data be downloaded via ATC facilities?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aircraft-maintenance, radio-communications

Could aircraft send maintenance data to the airport via ATC facilities (e.g., tower, TRACON, enroute)? Or are they only used for air traffic control?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you mean? What sort of maintenance requests? And what do you mean by ATC "facilities", do you mean ACARS?

Comment: By Maintenance data I mean the data that the airline or manufacturers may need for the plane maintenanc when the plane is on the ground. By  ATC facilities, I mean the ground stations that control the plane when a plane enters a new domain such as TRACON, enroute. I don’t know the technical name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not through ATC.  The airlines have "company" frequencies they can use for such data.  Outside of airlines, General Aviation can use FBO frequencies for the same communications.

Comment: Thanks. Through what facilities are these dara downloaded? Through tower near the airport? Hardware transfer? Or are there other facilities that the data can be sent to before landing?

Comment: If it is actual data on the aircraft, it can be transmitted to maintenance over ACARS, I assume.  Normally certain data, such as doors closed/opened at the gate, are transmitted this way for payroll purposes. Normal maintenance information is over voice coms on the Company frequency.  If there is data to be sent, there is agood chance it is more than a burned out light bulb and will require more time on the ground than scheduled.